# Why is this Retrofit field undefined?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying to pass a JSON body to a Node endpoint, and when I pass this code from my android app, the body is saying undefined once it hits the endpoint.

I want to pass the day of the week variable in the format {"dayOfTheWeek" : "Sunday} to the endpoint.

Here is my code that makes the retrofit call, dayOfTheWeek is a string declared up at the top of the file.

```
private void getLeaderStats() {

        Call<JsonArray> call = this.retroFit.getTopThreeUsers(dayOfTheWeek);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {
                String body = response.body().toString();

                Log.d("getTopThreeUsers", body);

                String splitter  = Pattern.quote("},{");
                String [] docs = body.split(splitter);

                usernames[0] = docs[0].substring(docs[0].indexOf("username") + 11, docs[0].indexOf("numberCorrect") - 3);
                usernames[1] = docs[1].substring(docs[1].indexOf("username") + 11, docs[1].indexOf("numberCorrect") - 3);
                usernames[2] = docs[2].substring(docs[2].indexOf("username") + 11, docs[2].indexOf("numberCorrect") - 3);

                scores[0] = docs[0].substring(docs[0].indexOf("numberCorrect") + 16, docs[0].indexOf("dayOfTheWeek") - 3);
                scores[1] = docs[1].substring(docs[1].indexOf("numberCorrect") + 16, docs[1].indexOf("dayOfTheWeek") - 3);
                scores[2] = docs[2].substring(docs[2].indexOf("numberCorrect") + 16, docs[2].indexOf("dayOfTheWeek") - 3);

                int i = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("getTopThreeUsers", "FAILED", t);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the Retrofit Interface:

```
public interface RetroFit {

    @GET("getRandomNames")
    Call<JsonArray> getRandomNames();

    @POST("getTopThreeUsers")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<JsonArray> getTopThreeUsers(@Field("dayOfTheWeek") String day);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    //The below can be done outside the class

    public static final Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl("http://ukko.d.umn.edu:24550")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

}
```

The getTopThreeUsers is the method I am using to call the node endpoint. When I run it, I put a console log in the endpoint which says that the value being passed to the endpoint is undefined. Also, when I run this method in postman and give it a JSON body, it works, which leads me to believe it is something with the retrofit.

Comment: try passing hashmap as paramter isntead of string

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server accepts as raw JSON body. Try this

```
@POST("getTopThreeUsers")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<JsonArray> getTopThreeUsers(@Body("dayOfTheWeek") String day);
```